# How to get first week of the every month ends with Thursday in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, cube

i have a difficult requirement that i need to show the first week of the every month should end with Thursday and second week start with Friday and ends with Thursday,
for example may first week should be 05/01/2016 - 05/05/2016 and
second week 05/06/2016 - 05/12/2016 and third week 05/13/2016 - 05/19/2016 and   fourth week 05/20/2016 - 05/26/2016 and fifth week 05/27/2016 - 05/31/2016.

**example**: when i select the March value in Month parameter it has to show like below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGrMH.jpg)

and i am building this report on CUBE data source, i need to do it in MDX

Comment: we need to see some mdx, plus we need to see the structure of your Date dimension - without this information how can we help?

Comment: That sounds to me like an Operations Week concept. Best practice is to have this logic implemented in your ETL layer not the MDX layer. Just my opinion!